# Looping animation of an FXB imported character

Tags: animation, looping

[image: Looping animation of an imported FXB file character]

I have looked at some of the answers given here and it does not seem to fit my situation.

1. The suggestion of using the NLA editor only repeats the animation as if it was a gif. In the attached clip I set the repeat to 2. I want the character to continue walking.
2. The other suggestion was to insert "Cyclic F-modifier" using Shift + E.  I tried that and no popup appeared.
3. The online video by Olaf which uses the node editor does not make it clear how to simply movement continues.

Any suggestion will be followed up on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am importing characters from Mixamo.  In order to get both the skin and key frames imported into Blender only the following procedure works.

1. When exporting from Mixamo make sure you select from the "Key Frame Reduction" either uniform or non-uniform.  The "Skin" setting defaults to with skin
   [image: Mixamo Download Screen]
2. I'm still using Blender version 2.79b so I don't know how this will work in v 2.8.
   I could only get it to work with the Blender Render engine.  Cycles engine imported neither the key frames which can be edited in the graph editor nor the skin.  So since Blender Render will not be available in 2.8, I would like to know if anyone has successfully imported characters from Mixamo with the skin and key frames?
   [image: Blender Render Engine]
3. But even in Blender Render once I change to another object and then change back the key frames are lost in the graph editor. Is there a way to display them again?
   [image]